# Apache URL Rewriting with n arguments

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm doing some URL rewriting and I can accomplish what I need to do with the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?arg1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You get what I'm trying to do here, I basically want to take the full url and parse it into individual arguments.  So /blah/test/asdf/hi would come in as arg1=blah, arg2=test, etc.

Now, if I want to expand this to 4 or 5 arguments, I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to present it rather than going out with ?arg1=$1&arg2=$2&arg3=$3 etc. etc.  I've seen people do this programatically (just take whole string with slashes and parse it in code) but I was curious if there was a way to do it with apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP to do that:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

$pathSegments = array_map('rawurldecode', explode('/', substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], 1)));
```

The first line is to get just the URL path from the request URL. The other line will remove the leading slash (`substr`), split into the segments (`explode`) and decode each segment (`array_map` with `rawrurldecode`).

Now you just need to pass all request to your *index.php*:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]
```

The additional condition will exclude requests that can be mapped to existing files.

Comment: Thanks for illustrating the programmatic approach that I mentioned.  It looks like that's the way it'll have to be done if I want this flexibility.

Comment: @epalla: Yes, absolutely. Your application knows best how to interpret the URLs. So it should do the URL interpretation as well and not mod_rewrite.